# How to Shuffle 2D List in java efficiently?

Tags: java, java-8

I need to create a 2D List that has random values from 1 to 16 on the list.
every time I call the function it should give me 2D list of 1 to 16 Values.

I am done this in this way

```
public List<List<Integer>> shuffle() {
    List<List<Integer>> ls = new ArrayList<>();
    ls.add(Arrays.asList(0, 0, 0, 0));
    ls.add(Arrays.asList(0, 0, 0, 0));
    ls.add(Arrays.asList(0, 0, 0, 0));
    ls.add(Arrays.asList(0, 0, 0, 0));
    Random rand = new Random();
    int x = 1, a, b;
    while (x < 17) {
        a = rand.nextInt(4);
        b = rand.nextInt(4);
        if (ls.get(a).get(b) == 0) {
            ls.get(a).set(b, x);
            x++;
        }
    }
    return ls;
}
```

this function **average take 75 loops to create 16 element 2D list**,
is that any other way to do it efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method name is already suggesting what has to be done. Instead of guessing the next index to set, just shuffle the elements. If you have shuffled values you can simply slice them into a 2-dimensional list.

```
public List<List<Integer>> create4x4RandomMatrix() {
    List<Integer> ints = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 16).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    Collections.shuffle(ints);
    List<List<Integer>> matrix = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        matrix.add(ints.subList(i * 4, (i + 1) * 4));
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

Since it is a fixed 4x4 matrix @Holger is right to create it in a static manner:

```
public List<List<Integer>> create4x4RandomMatrix() {
    List<Integer> ints = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 16).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    Collections.shuffle(ints);
    return Arrays.asList(ints.subList(0, 4), ints.subList(4, 8),
            ints.subList(8, 12), ints.subList(12, 16));
}
```

Comment: Since the 4×4 matrix is fixed, you could also use `return Arrays.asList(ints.subList(0, 4), ints.subList(4, 8), ints.subList(8, 12), ints.subList(12, 16));`

Answer (score 1):

The following should work faster:

1. Create a list of numbers 1-16.
2. Use `java.util.Collections.shuffle()` to shuffle that list.
3. Fill the 2D array from that list.

Here is a short example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;


public final class Shuffle {
   public static List<List<Integer>> shuffle() {
      int size = 4;
      ArrayList<Integer> all = new ArrayList();
      for (int i = 1; i <= size * size; ++i)
         all.add(i);
      Collections.shuffle(all, new Random());
      Iterator<Integer> number = all.iterator();

      List<List<Integer>> ls = new ArrayList<>();
      ls.add(Arrays.asList(0, 0, 0, 0));
      ls.add(Arrays.asList(0, 0, 0, 0));
      ls.add(Arrays.asList(0, 0, 0, 0));
      ls.add(Arrays.asList(0, 0, 0, 0));
      for (int a = 0; a < size; ++a) {
         for (int b = 0; b < size; ++b)
            ls.get(a).set(b, number.next());
      }
      return ls;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      List<List<Integer>> ls = shuffle();
      for (List<Integer> row : ls)
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row.toArray()));
   }
}
```